# magento stuck in billing information of checkout

Tags: magento-1.7

I fill billing information form and click on continue but dosn't work.
In firebug Response:
"OK
**Fatal error**:  Undefined class constant 'CHARS_PASSWORD_LOWERS' in **.../app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php** on line **381**
"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the file specified in the error you will find this:

```
$chars = Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_LOWERS
         . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_UPPERS
         . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_DIGITS
         . Mage_Core_Helper_Data::CHARS_PASSWORD_SPECIALS;
```

You get the error because for some reason in the class `Mage_Core_Helper_Data` there is (at least) one constant missing.
The following lines should be in the `Mage_Core_Helper_Data`:

```
const CHARS_SPECIALS                        = '!$*+-.=?@^_|~';
const CHARS_PASSWORD_LOWERS                 = 'abcdefghjkmnpqrstuvwxyz';
const CHARS_PASSWORD_UPPERS                 = 'ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const CHARS_PASSWORD_DIGITS                 = '23456789';
const CHARS_PASSWORD_SPECIALS               = '!$*-.=?@_';
```

Check this file `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php`.
There is also the possibility that the class was copied to the local folder and modified there, or it was copied before an upgrade. Check `app/code/local/Mage/Core/Helper/Data.php`